# insert images in another table with foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables in my db, `telephones(id, title, price)` and `images(id, tp_id, photos)` I went in the `images` table and put a foreign key on the `tp_id` column to match the `id` in the `telephones` table so that every image is linked to a `telephone`. But the problem is my images go into the table fine but the `tp_id` column always has the value of 0, what I am missing here? can somebody guide me? Thanks

PS: I know about the security vulnerability of my code I am just doing some test here!

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    include 'dbconnect.php';


    for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["photo"]["name"]); $i++) {


        $target = "img/"; //This is the directory where images will be saved 
        $target_files = $target . basename($_FILES['photo']['name'][$i]); //This gets all the other information from the form
        $ad_title = $_POST['title'];
        $ad_price = $_POST['price'];
        $ad_photo = $target . ($_FILES['photo']['name'][$i]);

        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_files)) { //Tells you if its all ok 
            echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
        } else { //Gives and error if its not 
            $sql = "INSERT INTO telephones (title, price) VALUES ('$ad_title', '$ad_price')";
            $conn->query($sql);

            $sql1 = "INSERT INTO images (photos) VALUES ('$ad_photo') ";
            $conn->query($sql1);
//Writes the photo to the server

            header('location: addconfirm.php');
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: **WARNING**: This code has severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because you're putting `$_POST` data directly into your query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 1):

get the last inserted primary key value using this

```
$last_id = $conn->insert_id;
```

Comment: on whcih query the second one?

Comment: @Juju get last inserted Id from first query and use in second query.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get last insert id form `telephones` table using [**`$conn->insert_id;`**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) and the insert into `images` table as

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO telephones (title, price) VALUES ('$ad_title', '$ad_price')";                      
            $conn->query($sql);
            $tp_id=$conn->insert_id;// get last insert id

 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO images (photos,tp_id) VALUES ('$ad_photo',$tp_id) ";
            $conn->query($sql1);
```

Note:- Your script is Open for sql injection check [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1) to prevent it

Comment: Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1):

Question has already been answered many times Use [: MySQL: LAST_INSERT_ID()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/getting-unique-id.html)

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO telephones (title, price) VALUES ('$ad_title', '$ad_price')";                      
 $conn->query($sql);
 $tp_last_insert_id = $conn->LAST_INSERT_ID;// get last insert id
```

you should call this function right after you insert to get the latest added id

```
 $sql1 = "INSERT INTO images (photos,tp_id) VALUES ('$ad_photo',$tp_last_insert_id) ";
  $conn->query($sql1);
```